# ¿Es correcto decir "desasignar"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, gramática, vocabulario

El término *desasignar* no aparece en el diccionario de la REA. Sin embargo, sí aparece [*asignar*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3zmNLMJ). En muchas aplicaciones informáticas se está usando el término desasignar, quizás por herencia del inglés.

Pero si hablamos de la acción de un usuario, con la capacidad para designar quién realizará *una tarea*, así como para hacer lo contrario ¿cuál sería el término?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La RAE [no incluye todas las palabras compuestas](http://www.rae.es/publicaciones/210-derivados-y-compuestos), solo aquellas que le parecen relevantes.

> Todas las voces derivadas de otras o formadas mediante composición, sin tener en cuenta la posibilidad de que su significado sea claramente deducible a partir de los elementos que las constituyen, pueden entrar a formar parte del Diccionario. Así sucede con los adverbios terminados en **-mente**, las voces que contienen los prefijos **anti-**, **des-**, etc. (...) En este Diccionario solo aparecen aquellos términos que, vista la documentación de su empleo real, el Pleno académico ha decidido incluir.

Las demás, se entiende que si usan los afijos (*des-*, *-mente*, etc.) y reglas habituales, y su significado es exactamente el esperado, entonces no necesitan aclaración.

Por ejemplo, *exmarido* es una palabra [perfectamente válida](http://www.rae.es/consultas/normas-de-escritura-de-los-prefijos-exmarido-ex-primer-ministro), pero [no aparece en el diccionario](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=exmarido).

En el caso que planteas, el significado de [asignar](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=asignar) está claro, y el del prefijo [des-](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=des-) también. Se entiende sin problema que la palabra quiere decir "deshacer la asignación".
**No aparece en el diccionario, pero es válida.**

<sub>Nota: todos los enlaces son a definiciones del DLE o artículos de la RAE, pero no los incluyo ya que son solo ilustrativos; el contenido no es necesario para entender la respuesta.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Que una palabra no aparezca en el diccionario no quiere decir que "no exista" o que "sea incorrecta". Si un afijo tiene un significado claro al añadirse a una base, no necesariamente estará en el diccionario la palabra resultante, ya que sería como explicar que 1 + 1 = 2.